# How to limit feeds module items to import to e.g. 10 in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, xpath, feed

I have successfully imported xml in my Drupal content type using feeds and xpath module. However, I am unable to set the numbers of nodes theat are created.

It is a problem becasue in the xml file there are 200 items, so it is slow. I would like to limit it to 30 items, so each time it updates only 30 nodes are created not 200.

Where to set this?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any configurations for this either. But Drupal 7 provides aggregator hooks that will allow you to override these.

Check out: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--aggregator--aggregator.api.php/function/hook_aggregator_fetch/7

Answer (score 0):

I think the question was about feeds module, not aggregator module.

In your settings.php file you can try setting
    $conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 50;
and then clear your caches.

However, the above method didn't work for me.  If you are just looking for a quick limiter (during development of a custom importer, for example) you can try the tip here: https://drupal.org/node/1909974